# Proving that angles outside a parallelogram are equal

Tags: geometry

The question given is: If lines $PB$ and $PD$ outside a parallelogram $ABCD$, make equal angles with sides $BC$and $DC$, respectively, then prove that $\angle CPB=\angle DPA$. [The figure is given in the following link.](http://ggbtu.be/m437259)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $Q$ be the point such that $DCPQ$ is a parallellogram. Then $APQD$ is cyclic ...

[image]

... because $\angle QPD = \angle PDC = \angle PBC = \angle QAD$ (the triangles $\triangle ADQ$ and $\triangle BCP$ are congruent).

Now it follows that $\angle CPB = \angle DQA = \angle DPA$, as desired.

Comment: How does that help??

Comment: I expanded my answer with a full explanation.

Comment: thanks...great picture..how did you get it in the answer?

Comment: If you press CTRL+G when typing your answer (or click on the image pictogram), you can upload a picture from your computer